# Slick2D crashes on Image.getGraphics() on some machines

Tags: opengl, graphics, lwjgl, slick

On some machines, creating a new Image and calling getGraphics() on it causes lwjgl to enter into some kind of faulty state that crashes when swapping buffers. Any idea what causes this and how to make Slick clean up after itself properly?

Reproduction code:

```
package crashrepro;

import org.newdawn.slick.*;

public class CrashRepro extends BasicGame {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CrashRepro cr = new CrashRepro("CrashRepro");
        // Crash only happens in fullscreen mode.
        AppGameContainer agc = new AppGameContainer(cr, 800, 600, true);
        agc.start();
    }

    public CrashRepro(String title) { super(title); }

    @Override
    public void init(GameContainer gc) throws SlickException {}

    @Override
    public void update(GameContainer gc, int i) throws SlickException {}

    @Override
    public void render(GameContainer gc, Graphics grphcs) throws SlickException {
        Image img = new Image(128, 128);
        img.getGraphics(); // This crashes the game.
    }
}
```

Stack trace:

```
Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsContextImplementation.nSwapBuffers(Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;)V+0
j  org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsContextImplementation.swapBuffers()V+35
j  org.lwjgl.opengl.ContextGL.swapBuffers()V+3
j  org.lwjgl.opengl.DrawableGL.swapBuffers()V+0
j  org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.swapBuffers()V+39
j  org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.update(Z)V+44
j  org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.update()V+1
j  org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.gameLoop()V+78
j  org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.start()V+17
j  crashrepro.CrashRepro.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+27
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out to have been caused by a lwjgl bug I reported [here](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl/issues/109).